# How to remove comments of ASM code

Tags: linux

I have an directory with about 300 source code in ASM.
So, I need to remove the comments (";") of this codes.

Until now, I removed the comments of 3 files, where each file has 100 lines of code.

Somebody know a script that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed is your friend:

```
find <asm_dir> -type f | xargs sed -i -e '/^;/d' -e 's/^\([^;]*\);.*$/\1/'
```

The first expression deletes lines that begin with the comment character `;`. The second expression strips inline comments (from `;` to the end of the line).

Comment: This command almost worked.
It didn't work in follow case:
 
mov ebx,[esi+eax*4+ac] ;take the left node


It didn't remove comments in this situation.

Comment: I didn't realize you had inline comments too. I'm not sure it's trivial to remove those, but if you're positive that your ASM won't contain a semicolon as part of the code, you can just delete any line that contains a semicolon anywhere: `find <asm_dir> -type f | xargs sed -i '/;/d'`.

Comment: @tkocmathla I think he means to delete the inline comments and keep the rest whereas your last suggestion would just delete it. Something like `s/([^;]*);.*/\1/g`? I'm not really good at sed but you'll get the point and repair me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply accomplish this in e.g. Vim or Emacs. I'm going to discuss Vim here.

Assuming you have all your .asm files in one directory go to your shell and do something like

```
cd /path/to/my/files
gvim *.asm
```

This will open all your .asm files for editing in gvim (graphical vim). If you are not familiar with Vim it's a great text editor and we are going to record a macro to do our job. Only do what I say or you will mess things up :) To be on the safe side you should backup your files in case you mistype something and delete more than you wish to.

Type these characters (or press the appropriate thing on your keyboard as specified in <>'s):

```
qa:g/^\s*;/d<Enter>:n<Enter>q
```

This will start recording a macro `[q]`, store it in `[a]`, execute a global deletion of every line in the first file that starts with optional whitespace followed by a semicolon `[:g/^\s*;/d<Enter>]`, move to the next file `[:n<Enter>]` and save the macro `[q]`. All you have to do now is run this macro as many times as you have files left. You can either get this by running `ls *.asm | wc -l` in your directory with the saved files or you can simply overshoot it and input a larger number, Vim will stop on the last file and notify you there's no more files to edit. So with the overshooting example you could type

```
1000@a
```

and the macro will start running through all the files. This may take some time so be patient. Once it's done we still haven't saved our files so we could check the results before commiting to them. You can check a couple of files if they look OK and if yes type

```
:wa<Enter>
```

All your files are saved now and you can exit Vim with `ZQ` or `:q<Enter>`.